# java.net.ConnectException when using rmi

Tags: java, rmi

I was reading Head First Design Patterns book when I got this code:

```
import java.rmi.*;
import java.rmi.*;

public class GumballMachineTestDrive {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GumballMachine gumballMachine = null;
        int count = 0;

        try {
            count = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
            gumballMachine = new GumballMachine(args[0], count);
            Naming.rebind("//" + args[0] + "/gumballmachine", gumballMachine);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

As they said in the book before I run this code, I made sure that i have rmiregisty running the background, but when I wrote this

```
C:\Users\Vision\Downloads\Desktop\New folder\StateAndProxy\build\classes>java 
gumball.GumballMachineTestDrive santafe.mightygumball.com 100
```

in command prompt i had this error

```
java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: santafe.mightygumball.com; nested 
    exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:623)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:209)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:196)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:343)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.rebind(RegistryImpl_Stub.java:150)
    at java.rmi/java.rmi.Naming.rebind(Naming.java:177)
    at gumball.GumballMachineTestDrive.main(GumballMachineTestDrive.java:17)
    Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:493)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:482)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:588)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:603)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:552)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:475)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:249)
    at 
    java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPDirectSocketFactory.createSocket
    (TCPDirectSocketFactory.java:40)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:617)
    ... 6 more
```

Any ideas what's the problem ??

Comment: It looks like the host for an Socket "santafe.mightygumbal.com" doesnt exist. So you try to reach a Socket which isnt there.

Comment: You can only rebind and unbind to a local `Registry` anyway, so specifying the hostname as anything but `localhost` is pointless.